Issue endpoint doesn't filter according to the query parameter value
I'm calling the issue endpoint with the query parameter to filter issues by a custom field value. But looks like the query parameter is ignored.
http://youtrack.qipx.sk:8080/api/admin/projects/io/issues?fields=id,idReadable,customFields(name,value(name,id))&query=Priorita:{2%20%20Stredna}
Custom field value

Any idea why the query parameter is ignored ? I tried replacing the curly brackets query=Priorita:%7B2%20%20Stredna%7D but the result is the same.
BTW Is it posible to query the custom field values by the enum id value ? (42-12)

Please try adding pluses as per these examples.

BTW Is it posible to query the custom field values by the enum id value ? (42-12)

No, the queries are basically the same as in the YouTrack UI, and it is not possible to use such IDs in UI.

Didn't help. query=Priorita:+%7B2++Stredna%7D The + should replace empty space ?
